# Cannot bind parameter error in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have below Azure Function which I am able to publish successfully and to debug , I ran it locally and I get the below error. Can someone please tell what this error is all about and how can I fix it?

My function code:

```
namespace MigrateDbWithChangeFeed
{
    
    public static class CopyFunction
    {
        [FunctionName( "MigrateWithChangeFeed" )]
        public static async Task Run( [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "sourcedb",
            collectionName: "sourcecollection",
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",            
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true
    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source, DocumentClient client,
    ILogger log )
        {
            string continuationToken = null;            
            do
            {
                var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( "sourcedb", "sourcecollection" ),
                    new SqlQuerySpec( "select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.ClassId)" ),
                    new FeedOptions
                    {
                        MaxItemCount = 100,
                        EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
                        RequestContinuation = continuationToken
                    } ).AsDocumentQuery();
                var result = await feed.ExecuteNextAsync();
                continuationToken = result.ResponseContinuation;
                foreach( var doc in result )
                {
                    string customerName = string.Empty;
                    var jsonContent = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( doc.ToString() );
                    customerName = (string)jsonContent["Customer"];
                    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( customerName ) )
                    {
                        customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping
                            .FirstOrDefault( q => q.Key.IndexOf( (string)jsonContent["Project"] ) != -1 ||
                            ((string)jsonContent["Project"]).IndexOf( q.Key ) != -1 ).Value ?? "Unknown";
                    }
                    string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( (string)jsonContent["ClassId"],
                        "|",
                        (string)jsonContent["Project"],
                        "|",
                        customerName );
                    jsonContent.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                   "dbname", "testtransform2" ),
                   jsonContent );

                }
            }
            while( continuationToken != null );

        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>( File.ReadAllText( "CustomerSection.json" ) );
    }
    
}
```

> Error indexing method 'MigrateWithChangeFeed'
> [2021-08-25T08:58:18.983Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
> indexing method 'MigrateWithChangeFeed'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
> Cannot bind parameter 'client' to type DocumentClient. Make sure the
> parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding
> extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure
> you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your
> startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.). [2021-08-25T08:58:18.984Z] Function
> 'MigrateWithChangeFeed' failed indexing and will be disabled.
> [2021-08-25T08:58:18.986Z] No job functions found. Try making your job
> classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
> Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
> registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
> builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
> builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Comment: Is this in-proc model or out of process (.net 5) ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `DocumentClient client` from the method parameter list and try to initialize it your self (you probably want a singleton instance to avoid running into connection exhaustion situation)

Comment: if i initialize client by my self ,then it works